# How to revert GCC installation on Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, gcc, matlab

I recently installed gcc 6.3.0 following the instructions on this [site](https://linuxhostsupport.com/blog/how-to-install-gcc-on-centos-7/) as it is the supported compiler for the 2018b release of Matlab and Simulink.
However due to compatibility issues with other software I need to revert to Matlab 2016a and are trying to install the supported version of gcc which is 4.7.0 or at least to revert to the default Centos-7 gcc version which is 4.8.5.

I have been unsuccessful in either. When trying to reinstall gcc 4.8.5 by using:

```
yum -y install gcc
```

I get the following message:

```
Package gcc-4.8.5-36.el7_6.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

But Matlab still runs gcc 6.3.0 when trying to compile mex files.

Can somebody point me in the right direction of where to start looking for a solution?

I am completely new with linux or managing operating systems through a command terminal, so step by step guides explaining what each step does would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You propably have the compiled gcc 6.3.0 version resolved before the installed one. Check your PATH, `echo $PATH`, most likely the gcc 6.3.0 executable was stored in the `/usr/local/bin` directory.

Try for example moving the gcc executable in `/usr/local/bin` to a packup location, `mkdir /tmp/gcc_bak && sudo mv /usr/local/bin/gcc /tmp/gcc_bak/` and check gcc version again, `gcc --version`.

If you find that the default Centos-7 gcc was overwritten you could try reinstalling with `sudo yum reinstall gcc`.

**Note**: if you're doing the above, there might be more gcc executables lurking in the `/usr/local/bin` directory, try running for example `ls -al /usr/local/bin | grep gcc`, you might want to get those out of the way too.